# Autodesk Inventor 2024 Inventor Design Automation - FailedEnvironmentSetup

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I was hoping to confirm if the engine for Inventor 2024 is available for Inventor Design Automation on APS or is support still being worked on.

I was able to upload a native 2024 model yesterday but not able to configure it and kept receiving the "*Job finished with result FailedEnvironmentSetup*" error even though it is listed as supported according to the API.

[image: currently supported engines]

As of today, I'm not able to upload a new model or configure the existing one and receive the same error.

I'm hoping for a current status update on the 2024 engine to determine if it is something more on our end that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **Inventor 2024** is still not supported on **Design Automation** and showed up in the list by mistake.

We are working on making it available as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Please do keep us posted!